# Removing background color removes axes lines as well

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below

```
Target_Category<-c("Adhesion","Cytochrome")
Validated<-c(5,10)
Candidate<-c(7,8)
dataf<-data.frame(Target_Category,Validated,Candidate)
```

And I create a stacked bar plot with

```
dataf %>%
  gather(col, value, -Target_Category) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(Target_Category, value, fill = col), stat="identity")+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

The issue is that when I try to remove the background color with

```
theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

the x and y axes are disappeared as well.

Comment: Have you tried `theme_minimal()` ?

Comment: `theme_bw()` removes only the background grey colour.

Comment: The default color of the axis is white and so is the backgroud when you call `theme(panel.background = element_blank())`. Add `+ theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "black"))` or call `theme_*` as Yuriy and Nacho suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
library(tidyverse)    
dataf %>%
  gather(col, value, -Target_Category) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(aes(Target_Category, value, fill = as.factor(col)), stat="identity")+
  theme_classic()
```

The trick is coercing `col` to factor. By the way in your question, the `dataf` has no column called `col`